# Hide custom fields by user's role

Tags: custom-field, user-roles

I've tried reading all the questions about this topic, and configured the code to fit my needs, but can't seem to get it to work. This is the code I have now:

```
function my_exclude_custom_fields( $protected, $meta_key, $user ) {

    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( in_array( 'udlejer', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
        if ( in_array( $meta_key, array( 'email', 'text' ) ) ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return $protected;
}
add_filter( 'is_protected_meta', 'my_exclude_custom_fields', 10, 2 );
```

It doesn't make any change. Even though I'm logged in with another role than `udlejer`, I can still see these custom fields in front-end.

The custom fields are on a product page created by WooCommerce. Do I then need to include more to the code then? Hope you guys can help!

Comment: Where is `$currentUser` coming from? Your codes formatting is broken, can you fix it? Code is easier to read/fix with good formatting :)

Comment: I think it's fixed now. Thanks for pointing it out :) I'm new at coding. But still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `current_user_can()` function to test the current user's role. I would also recommend making the custom field protected by default and allowing access only to the proper users.

In theory, something like this should work:

```
function my_exclude_custom_fields( $protected, $meta_key) {

    if ( in_array( $meta_key, array( 'email', 'text' ) ) ) {
        if ( current_user_can( 'udlejer' ) ) {
            // meta key is not protected for user role 'udlejer'
            return false;
        } else {
            // make the meta keys protected by default
            return true;
        }
    }

    return $protected;
}
add_filter( 'is_protected_meta', 'my_exclude_custom_fields', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It gives me an error regarding: 'if ( current_user_can( 'udlejer' ) ) {'  - syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)  -  What to do in this case? I've tried adding semicolon, but still same error.

Comment: Oops! It looks like I missed a ")" to end the IF statement that is checking the meta key (the first IF). I updated the code to fix the error.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply and fix! No errors now, but all users can still view the custom fields on the product page :/

Comment: Hmmm... How did you create the 'udlejer' role? You could experiment with testing against an existing role or capability. Those can be seen here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

It may also be worth troubleshooting by returning false after the first IF no matter what to make sure that protecting the meta_key will even hide it from users.

Comment: It's created with Paid Memberships Pro. I figured out, that udlejer is - pmpro_role_3 and changed it in the code, but still no difference. Afterwards i tried return false; after the first IF, but still nothing different. The custom fields are created with WP User Frontend Pro, as meta keys - "email" and "text"